# Keydown event not emitted for Tab/Next key from mobile browser in a HTML form

Tags: html, forms, mobile

In an HTML form with two text inputs the Tab/Next key event is not emitted.  It is emitted for the last text field in the form.

You can run this from a mobile browser at.  (I tried chrome and firefox on Android):

In the first text field press the tab key and no event will be emitted, in the second, and last field, the event will be emitted.

My question is there a way to capture the traversal event for text fields that are NOT the last text field in the form?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWJTQYI457YB

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</p>
<form>
<input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction()">
<input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction()">
</form>
<script>

function myFunction() {
    alert("You pressed a key inside the input field");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```